# discord.py Reaction Roles AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'guild'

Tags: python, discord.py, roles

Sorry if this is a bad question but I can't find a solution to this anywhere and I've been trying for two days to make reaction roles work for my bot
it gives the output:

```
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'guild'
```

```
  @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_raw_reaction_add(self, payload):
        reaction_message_id = 1067231301452701748
        user = payload.user_id
        user_reaction = str(payload.emoji)
        if reaction_message_id != payload.message_id:
            return`
        if user_reaction == '<a:rose-1:1066240347769942066>':
            role = discord.utils.get(user.guild.roles, name="Red")
            await user.add_roles(role)
```

This should change my role on reaction. I'm not sure what I need to do for this this line to work

```
role = discord.utils.get(user.guild.roles, name="Red")
```

Comment: What do you think `user` is after `user = payload.user_id`?

Comment: @Brian its just the user_id of the discord user who reacts so it can make sure to assign the role to them

Comment: ids are (nearly always) integers.  Why do you expect an integer to have a `.guild` attribute?

Answer (score 0):

So the problem is `user = payload.user_id` so now `user` is now user id which is int and later when you tried to get `user.guild` so the user was id (also int) which has no attribute like guild.

what you did:

```py
  @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_raw_reaction_add(self, payload):
        reaction_message_id = 1067231301452701748
        user = payload.user_id # returns 1234567890
        user_reaction = str(payload.emoji)
        if reaction_message_id != payload.message_id:
            return`
        if user_reaction == '<a:rose-1:1066240347769942066>':
            role = discord.utils.get(user.guild.roles, name="Red") # here its the 123456789
            await user.add_roles(role)
```

the correct method

```py
  @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_raw_reaction_add(self, payload):
        reaction_message_id = 1067231301452701748
        user = payload.member # here it returns memebr object 
        user_reaction = str(payload.emoji)
        if reaction_message_id != payload.message_id:
            return`
        if user_reaction == '<a:rose-1:1066240347769942066>':
            role = discord.utils.get(user.guild.roles, name="Red")
            await user.add_roles(role)
```